# How to use custom token model in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I'd like to use Django Rest Framework auth but I want to have more than one token for one user. In order to do that I need to implement my own Token model, I found this in Token authentication class:

```
class TokenAuthentication(BaseAuthentication):
    """
    Simple token based authentication.
    ...
    """

    model = Token
    """
    A custom token model may be used, but must have the following properties.

    * key -- The string identifying the token
    * user -- The user to which the token belongs
    """
```

But I don't have an idea how I can specify this model. Should I subclass `TokenAuthentication`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What that message is saying is that the model `Token` can be swapped out with any other model, as long as it has properties `key` and `user`. That way, if, for instance, you want a more complicated way to generate token keys, you can define your own model.

So if you want a custom Token model, you should do the following:

1. Subclass the Token model from `rest_framework.authtoken.models`. Add whatever custom behavior you want here, but make sure it has a `key` property and `user` property.
2. Subclass the TokenAuthentication class from `rest_framework.authentication`. Set its `model` property to whatever your new Token model is.
3. Make sure to reference your new authentication class in whatever views you want.

Comment: Hi Jamie, i'm using rest_framework.authtoken.models Token. i can see 3 fields which is key, created_at and user_id. my question is how can i add an extra field like company_id to that model? Thanks

Answer (score 17):

Define you own authentication method in `settings.py`:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'my_project.my_app.authentication.MyOwnTokenAuthentication',
     ),
}
```

In `authentication.py`:

```
from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication
from my_project.my_app.models.token import MyOwnToken

class MyOwnTokenAuthentication(TokenAuthentication):
    model = MyOwnToken
```

In `models.py`:

```
import binascii
import os

from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from my_project.companies.models import Company


class MyOwnToken(models.Model):
    """
    The default authorization token model.
    """
    key = models.CharField(_("Key"), max_length=40, primary_key=True)

    company = models.OneToOneField(
        Company, related_name='auth_token',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Company"
    )
    created = models.DateTimeField(_("Created"), auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Token")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Tokens")

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.key:
            self.key = self.generate_key()
        return super(MyOwnToken, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def generate_key(self):
        return binascii.hexlify(os.urandom(20)).decode()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.key
```

Comment: but, how can I call "MyOwnTokenAuthentication" from view?

Comment: @RajuSingh you don't need to add anything to views, after you define DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES, you're defining MyOwnTokenAuthentication as middleware function. Then, on your APIViews, you can access the authenticated user with "self.request.user" .  You can also define authentication per view basis: authentication_classes  = [MyOwnTokenAuthentication]

Comment: Getting `'MyOwnToken' object has no attribute 'user'` when trying to use this approach. It seems to me that it still has to be connected with a user, is that correct?